# How to convert standard IP address format string to hex and long?

Tags: c++, format, ip-address

Does anyone know how to get the IP address in decimal or hex from standard IP address format string ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")?

I've tried to use the inet_addr() function but didn't get the right result.

I tested it on "84.52.184.224"

the function returned 3770168404 which is not correct (the correct result is 1412741344).

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs functions can be used to convert between network and local byte orders.

Answer (score 25):

You have just got the bytes reversed from what you expected - they are in [network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking)

```
3770168404 = 0xE0 B8 34 54     network byte order
               |         |
                \       /
                 \     /
                  \   /
                   \ /
                   /\
                  /  \   
                 /    \
                /      \
               |        |
1412741344 = 0x54 34 B8 E0     machine order
```

You could use [ntohl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740069(VS.85).aspx) convert from network order to machine order.

Answer (score 4):

The returned result is correct, the bytes are ordered in network byte order

```
84 => 0x54
52 => 0x34
184 => 0xb8
224 => 0xe0
0xe0b83454 => 3770168404
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be running into a byte order issue. From the man page:

> All Internet addresses are returned in network order (bytes ordered from
>        left to right).  All network numbers and local address parts are returned
>        as machine byte order integer values.

Comment: I've noticed the byte order is reverse. e0b83454 - 5434B8E0. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Carefully check the below link:

http : // msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738563(VS.85).aspx