# Hexadecimal IP to String using C++

Tags: c++, string, ip, hex

I have Hexadecimal format IP4 address which needs to be converted to string. Could you please let me know what needs to be changed in the below code to get the right answer. Thanks a lot for the support.

```
int main (void) {
char buff[16];
string  IpAddressOct = "EFBFC845";
string xyz="0x"+IpAddressOct+"U";
unsigned int iStart=atoi(xyz.c_str());
sprintf (buff, "%d.%d.%d.%d", iStart >> 24, (iStart >> 16) & 0xff,(iStart >> 8) & 0xff, iStart & 0xff);
printf ("%s\n", buff);
return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is 0.0.0.0, but expected output is 239.191.200.69

Comment: Guessing that your `atoi` doesn't recognize `0xEFBFC845U`. `strtoul` can do the trick with the right args and if you remove the `U`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert standard IP address format string to hex and long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491060/how-to-convert-standard-ip-address-format-string-to-hex-and-long)

Comment: printf("%s\n",xyz); is empty. I guess atoi is not having the issue.

Comment: In the entire stackoverflow site I did not get the right answer. In the link shared by Steve, there is no code or the conversion logic shared for Hex IP to String, instead there are answers for the other way round. This is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atoi() only takes integers. If you call atoi("1"), it will return 1. If you call atoi("a"), it will return 0.

What you should do is create a mapping between hex values and do the calculation every two character. The following is an example:

```
  1 #include <map>
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 #include <cstring>
  4 #include <string>
  5 #include <vector>
  6
  7 using namespace std;
  8
  9 static std::map<unsigned char, int> hexmap;
 10
 11 void init() {
 12     hexmap['0'] = 0;
 13     hexmap['1'] = 1;
 14     hexmap['2'] = 2;
 15     hexmap['3'] = 3;
 16     hexmap['4'] = 4;
 17     hexmap['5'] = 5;
 18     hexmap['6'] = 6;
 19     hexmap['7'] = 7;
 20     hexmap['8'] = 8;
 21     hexmap['9'] = 9;
 22     hexmap['a'] = 10;
 23     hexmap['A'] = 10;
 24     hexmap['b'] = 11;
 25     hexmap['B'] = 11;
 26     hexmap['c'] = 12;
 27     hexmap['C'] = 12;
 28     hexmap['d'] = 13;
 29     hexmap['D'] = 13;
 30     hexmap['e'] = 14;
 31     hexmap['E'] = 14;
 32     hexmap['f'] = 15;
 33     hexmap['F'] = 15;
 34 }
 35
 36 vector<int> parseIp(string income) {
 37     vector<int> ret;
 38     if (income.size() > 8)
 39         // if incoming string out of range
 40         return ret;
 41     int part = 0;
 42     char buf[4];
 43     for (int i = 0; i < income.size(); ++i) {
 44         part += hexmap[income[i]];
 45         cout << income[i] << " " << hexmap[income[i]] << " " << part << endl;
 46         if ((i % 2) == 1) {
 47             ret.push_back(part);
 48             part = 0;
 49         } else {
 50             part *= 16;
 51         }
 52     }
 53
 54     return ret;
 55 }
 56
 57 int main(void) {
 58     init();
 59     string ipAddressOct = "EFBFC845";
 60     vector<int> ip = parseIp(ipAddressOct);
 61     cout << ip[0] << "." << ip[1] << "." << ip[2] << "." << ip[3] << endl;
 62 }
```

The above could be overly complicated. It is intended for example only.